# Problema con formulario PHP

Tags: php, html5, phpmyadmin

Estoy queriendo vincular un PHP de contacto, me llegan los mails pero me redirige a una pagina en blanco. Mi html:

[Dejo el adjunto de la pagina](http://www.estudioovejero.com.ar/)

Mi PHP:

```
<?php
$remitente = $_POST['email'];
$destinatario = 'MAIL'; 
$asunto = 'Consulta ovejero';
if (!$_POST){
?>  
<?php
}else{

    $cuerpo = "Nombre: " . $_POST["name"] . "\r \n"; 
    $cuerpo .= "Email: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r \n";
    $cuerpo .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST["message"] . "\r\n"

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
    $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n";
    $headers .= "From: \"".$_POST['name']." ".$_POST['message']."\" <".$remitente.">\n";   
    mail($destinatario, $asunto, $cuerpo, $headers);
```

Comment: Buenas, no entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer? con el codigo que has compartido entiendo que enviar un mail. lo que quieres es cuando se mande el mail que te redirija a otra pagina?, si es asi indica cual y te explico como hacerlo

Comment: Nono, cuando apreto el boton de ENVIAR, manda el mensaje al mail pero me redirije a una pagina en blanco.

Comment: Pero quiero decir que tu quieres que cuando le des a enviar te redirija a donde? a la pagina principal? "http://www.estudioovejero.com.ar/"

Comment: claro, que no salga de la pagina donde estoy, luego agregare un alert de mensaje enviado.

Comment: Te estoy haciendo una respuesta amplia para explicarte varias formas de hacerlo

Comment: Ahora te desarrollo la segunda opcion, prueba esta mientras para comprobar que te funcione

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera forma para redireccionar con el código que tienes hecho es la siguiente:

```
<?php

ob_start();

$remitente = $_POST['email'];
$destinatario = 'MAIL'; 
$asunto = 'Consulta ovejero';
if (!$_POST){
?>  
<?php
}else{
$cuerpo = "Nombre: " . $_POST["name"] . "\r \n"; 
$cuerpo .= "Email: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r \n";
$cuerpo .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST["message"] . "\r\n"

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n";
$headers .= "From: \"".$_POST['name']." ".$_POST['message']."\" <".$remitente.">\n";   

if (mail($destinatario, $asunto, $cuerpo, $headers)){
     header("Location: **LA DIRECCION DE TU INDEX O A LA QUE QUIERAS ENVIARLA**")
}

}

ob_end_flush();
```

La primera diferencia es `ob_start();` y al final `ob_end_flush(),` esto básicamente lo que hace es crear un buffer que guarda todos los envios de las header y las envia todas a la vez (`Para evitar el error de Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by` ). Y con esto ya te debería redirigir correctamente

Comment: ahi lo pruebo, gracias!

Comment: me tira un error "no se puede procesar la pagina"

Comment: Y ese error donde lo defines tu? puedes añadirlo a la pregunta?, tambien puedes probar haciendo mail($destinatario, $asunto, $cuerpo, $headers)
     header("Location: **LA DIRECCION DE TU INDEX O A LA QUE QUIERAS ENVIARLA**"), quitandole el if pero asi no te cercioras de que se envia antes de redireccionarte
}

Comment: le faltaba un break al final, con eso se soluciono :)

Comment: @MaguiiTa te sirvio la respueta?